# Magento new customer account confirmation template edit

Tags: magento

I have tried to edit new customer account confirmation template in magento. But it not reflect in front end.

I have edited the layout for `customer_account_confirmation` in customer.xml file in theme layout folder.

I have edited  `customer_account_confirmation` in customer.xml

```
<customer_account_confirmation>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/account_confirm.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Send confirmation link</title></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_confirmation>
```

When i tried to click the confirmation link from mail it redirect to dashboard page and show confirmation message. 
But i need to show the thank you page for after customer click confirmation link from mail

I would like to set the thank you page in account_confirm.phtml file in template folder.But this is not working.

Can suggest me the right solution to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: have you cleared the cache before testing? Also, give a Mage::log in account_confirm.phtml, it will let you know if that template file is actually used.

Comment: yes i have disabled my cache and compilation.after click the link it only redirect to account dashboard page and show the confirnation message.

Comment: may be something is wrong in the file. can you post the snippet of code you wrote to show the thank you page on clicking the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right, your problem is: How to change the redirect URL which gets called when a customer clicks on the confirmation link for her new account?

In this case, check for the controller which is in charge for the default redirect (which is to "dashboard"). You can find it easily by examining the URL which is given in the confirmation link, which is something like `http://www.yourdomain.com/customer/account/confirm/[some params]`. From here you get the controller: You are looking for the `confirmAction()` method, which is in the `AccountController.php` of the Customer Modul. 
At the end of this method a redirect is defined:

```
public function confirmAction()  {
    (...)

            // log in and send greeting email, then die happy
            $this->_getSession()->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $successUrl = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer, true);
            $this->_redirectSuccess($backUrl ? $backUrl : $successUrl);
            return;

    (...)
}
```

So, on a succesful confirmation, the user is redirected to either the URL given in `$backUrl`, or, if this is not given, to the URL given in`$successUrl`.

The first variable `$backUrl` is defined inside this `confirmAction()` method, if the confirmation link URL contains a parameter `back_url`:

`$backUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back_url', false);`

The second variable `$succesUrl` is returned by the `_welcomeCustomer()` method of the `AccountController`, which sets an URL pointing to the `indexAction()`, loading the customer's dashboard.

So, in order to change the default Magento redirect, you can either make sure that your confirmation link is created with a `back_url` parameter (in my case, for example, this parameter is empty); or you override the `AccountController` in a custom modul and make the redirect as you wish.